# Accessing the DOM representation of a template instance that is calling a helper

Tags: templates, meteor

I am trying to access a DOM element corresponding to the particular template instance that is calling a helper function. As I read the Meteor documentation, Template.instance() should return the template instance object that called the helper, and something like Template.instance().$() would allow me to grab DOM elements within that instance.

However, the following code (and similar variations) is not working for me:

*** HTML ***

```
<template name="input_container">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-6 columns empty {{isActive}}"></div>
</template>
```

*** JS ***

```
Template.input_container.helpers({
   isActive: function() {
       if (Template.instance().$('.empty') && [some Session variable logic] {
           return 'active';
       }
   }
});
```

When I do something like:

```
if (some Session logic) {
    console.log(Template.instance())
}
```

I get the helper properly logging multiple versions of:

`Blaze.TemplateInstance {view: Blaze.View, data: 7, 
firstNode: div.small-12.medium-12.large-6.columns.empty.active-container,
lastNode: div.small-12.medium-12.large-6.columns.empty.active-container, $: function…}`

(With data: values going from 1-12 appropriately, but otherwise each seems to be the same)

How do I get from this to being able to used the template methods such as template.$ or template.find?

EDIT:

While not a perfect solution, I did manage to work around some of these issues by using Template.currentData() and setting an identifier on each instance of the input.

```
Template.create_form.helpers(
  # Create 12 input containers
  inputContainer: () ->
    [0..11]
```

And then:

```
Template.input_container.helpers(

isActive: () ->
    # Get which template instance we are working with, will return the number 0-11 that was used to create it
    current = Template.currentData()

    # Now I can do $(".input-container").eq(current) to grab the correct DOM element
```

)

But it seems a little dirty to need to use so much jQuery.

Comment: Did you mean `Template.instance().$('.empty').length > 0`? In javascript an empty array is not considered falsy value.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped that. What I'm looking to check is something like Template.instance().$('div').hasClass('empty')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've interpreted the question correctly, but if you're trying to access another DOM element on the page - I was able to use a jquery selector.

For example, given html of

```
<input type="textfield" id="initials" value=" ">
```

and a simple meteor template of

```
<template name="demo">
    <input type="button" div id="s0">
</template>
```

I can successfully access the initials field when the s0 button is clicked as follows

```
Template.demo.events({
   'click .cell': function(event, template) {
        if ($('#initials').val().trim().length > 0) {
           console.log($('#initials').val().trim() + ' - you clicked button '+$(event.target).attr('id'));
    }
},
```